# Return from function shouln't be None

Tags: python, indexoutofrangeexception

Why does this function result in:

> Oops, try again. remove_duplicates([]) resulted in an error: list index out of range"?

my function is as follows

```
def remove_duplicates(listIn):
    listSorted = sorted(listIn)
    prevInt = listSorted[0]
    listOut = []
    listOut.append(prevInt)
    for x in listSorted:
        if (x != prevInt):
            prevInt = x
            listOut.append(x)

    print listOut

    return listOut

remove_duplicates([1,2,3,3,3])
```

which outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3]
None
```

Thank you.

Comment: Because you cannot index an empty list `listSorted[0]` so  `remove_duplicates([])` will obviously error.  The only way you get None for the second part of your question is if you don't actually have a `return listOut` Add a `if not listIn:return []` to fix the first issue

Comment: works for me as well

Comment: lastly your code is not recursive it is iterative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your question you need to just check for the length of your list and return if its empty

```
if not listIn:
    return []
```

however your whole approach could be simplified with a set like so

```
def remove_duplicates(listIn):
    return list(set(listIn))
```

output:

```
>>> print remove_duplicates([1,2,3,3,3])
>>> [1, 2, 3]
```

of course this is assuming you want to keep your data in a list.. if you dont care then remove the outer `list()` conversion to make it faster. regardless this will be a much faster approach than what you have written

Comment: `if not listIn` is enough to catch an empty list using python.

Comment: The list I'm returning, listOut, isn't empty.  I print it out before returning it, and it shows 3 elements.  So, why am I receiving "error: list index out of range"?  listSorted isn't empty either.  It has 5 elements.  Sorry if I'm missing something.  Thanks.

Comment: @mattL if you look at the output... the first time its printing out what you wanted.. then theres another print... it also said `remove_duplicates([])` you can see the empty list there. so somewhere its getting called with an empty list... but seriously consider changing it to use a set like I put in my answer... sets store unique elements so it removes duplicates for you :)

Comment: Thanks John.  I see why the confusion now.  I'm in the middle of a codecademy Python course, and this expression, remove_duplicates([1,2,3,3,3]), is how the method, remove_duplicates(), is manually invoked.  I like your suggestion and I recognize it's efficiency.  But, I'm learning Python fundamentals, and I'd sure like to know why my code is throwing the list index out of range error.  My code seems simple enough.  If I take that last statement out, then Codecademy injects its own code to test the efficacy of my code, and their test code results in the same error.  Thanks.

Comment: @mattL if you have a second [go here](http://codeshare.io/Zmy3J).. and i'll show you whats happening

Comment: Thanks John.  I tried to connect with you at Codeshare.  The thing is though, if I make it, prevInt = listSorted[0]
    print prevInt

Comment: prevInt = listSorted[0]
    print prevInt, it shows that listSorted isn't empty because prevInt is populated with 1.

Comment: You aren't understanding what I'm saying.. The function is called more than once... The first time it works fine and is printing out `[1,2,3]` the second time its called with an empty list printing out None

Comment: Thanks John.  Any idea on why I'm getting, "Oops, try again. remove_duplicates([]) resulted in an error: list index out of range"?"

Comment: @mattL not sure.. something is printing that out.. i'd have to see the code lol... but it shows that `remove_duplicates([])` was called like that with an empty list.. which is why its giving the list index out of range.. so with that check it should solve the issue